# tornado-sockjs, how to set session id from client?

Tags: tornado, sockjs

I want to create realtime application and i want to send realtime updates only for specific users (for example my friends).

I have list of friend ids and my own id on client side. As I understand, I need to set sockjs session with my own id when I connect for my friends to be able to find me later when they send events.

The problem that I cant find where I can set the session id? The sockjs-client doesn't allows to send parameters with url on connect..

Answer (score 2):

The usual way is to treat the first message sent over sockjs specially. If you send your authorization / username / cookie / whatever as a first message from sockjs-client, you can receive that in sockjs server and mark this connection as fits.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. Now i thought about opening connection to url with user id as part of url (not arguments). This should be easy to extract them with regex.

Comment: Can I set the url to /info by myself? Because it always append it to endpoint?

Comment: Request to `/info` is part of SockJS protocol, no, user is not allowed to interfere with that. But you can indeed pass magical options to SockJS constructor that will cause SockJS-client not to call /info. This is _not_ recommended though.

Comment: will setting session_id as browser cookie help??

Comment: Just send the user name and any metadata you need as the first message over sockjs.

Comment: @Marek: Can you tell me how to close the WS Connection if client doesn't send the metadata in first request as need?